# Programmaticaly change mini-cart Subtotal text to Total if free shipping - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

By default the woocommerce mini-cart shows the text "Subtotal" regardless if free shipping is available or not and prices already include taxes. How to programmaticaly change the text to "Total" if free shipping is set for the cart?

[image]